# What are the possible reasons for an Engine Knock?

Tags: engine, knock

I have a Perodua Viva Elite (2011 MT). Several months back my vehicle engine started to knock and Engine Check Light started showing up while driving in traffic. So I went for an Injector replacement, then every thing was back to normal. But now it seems that the problem isn't solved at all. Now it's been about 8 moths after the injector replacement and guess what the knock is back again.

> **So I would like to know, what causes the engine to knock?**

Comment: Welcome to the site. There are a many things that can cause an engine to knock. So before people start guessing what is causing this, please tell us what the **Check Engine Light** codes were or are. If you don't know, have them read and update your question with them. This will be very helpful in helping you resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

if it is a very loud and continuous knock, one possibility is worn piston rod bearings. If its a quieter tick then i think that a noticeable yet not loud ticking could be lifters. Also, I think, but not sure, that another possibility could be a dirty throttle body restricting the plate from opening all the way and instead, flapping in the throttle body. Could also be a crack in the exhaust letting out air. Im sure there are many other possibilities to this noise but using an OBDII scanner should at least narrow it down a bit.