# Oil change: level was so low it didn't show on the dip-stick?

Tags: engine, oil, knock

Had the oil changed and they said it didn't show on the dip-stick. Now it seems like the engine could be knocking a little. Could it be damaged? confused

Comment: so how low was it and does it show on the stick now?  Also can I suggest you hit edit and fix a bunch of spelling errors and random misplaced punctuation marks?

Answer (score 1):

Without oil the engine could be damaged, yes. Oil is essential to keeping your engine running and healthy.

An [engine knock can be a sign of problems](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/42428/37) so get it thoroughly checked out.

Answer (score 0):

Is it right dipstick? Have you changed it?
If it is right dipstick which came with your vehicle then you need to add another litre of oil.
Be sure before pouring oil there is no leakage in the engine where oil can be gone out.
The engine can be knocking for many reasons including low oil.

Comment: Welcome to the site. The answer area is not the place to ask clarifying questions. Use the comments area for that. I understand you don't have enough reputation yet, but you will soon.